Latest trends and bench marks for VASP on GPU
I am thinking of getting a server with a GPU system for VASP calculations, and I am interested in learning about the latest benchmarks on these topics. Does anyone have a reference to the latest performance benchmarks?
I am on a budget so I am likely going to buy an older GPU system and I wonder if it is going to be worth it. I also need a bit of advice on what combination of CPU and GPU would be ideal.

On modern hardware (A100s etc.) VASP will run well, I can't provide a reference immediately but NERSC published something I think.  Older GPUs (especially consumer) will struggle due to VRAM and older Compute Capability though.  Consumer GPUs will be super slow due to double precision being needed.
Not making this an answer because it's really not a direct answer to your question.

Please note that you need an NVIDIA card with good 64-bit floating-point performance, which means you must get a Tesla-class GPU compute card (not a consumer-level card) and avoid the ones which are poor for 64-bit maths (e.g. don't get an A40). In general, the V100, A100, H100 are all good.
